# Question regarding how the annihilation operator is explained by Shankar

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm reading Shankar's quantum mechanics textbook and I am on the part about ladder operators. The portion where he explains the function of the annihilation operator goes as follows:

$$\hat{H}a|\epsilon\rangle = (a\hat{H} - [a, \hat{H}])|\epsilon\rangle = (a\hat{H} - a)|\epsilon\rangle = (\epsilon-1)a|\epsilon\rangle$$
From this it can be understood that $a|\epsilon\rangle$ is an eigenstate with eigenvalue $\epsilon-1$. I understand up to here. He then writes $$a|\epsilon\rangle = C_{\epsilon}|\epsilon-1\rangle$$ (where the kets are already normalized).

What is the role of $C_\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whi;e $|\epsilon\rangle$ and $|\epsilon-1\rangle$ are normalized, there is no reason to expect $a|\epsilon\rangle$ to be normalized. So $C_\epsilon$ is there to give the normalization of  $a|\epsilon\rangle$.  We find that
$$
\langle \epsilon| a^\dagger a |\epsilon\rangle = |C_\epsilon|^2 \langle \epsilon-1|\epsilon-1 \rangle= |C_\epsilon|^2, 
$$
so knowing the expectation value of $a^\dagger a$ in the state $|\epsilon\rangle$ gives you $|C_\epsilon|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Both $a|\epsilon\rangle$ and $|\epsilon-1\rangle$ are evidently $H$ eigenstates with eigenvalues $(\epsilon-1)$. (The latter, by definition; the former you just  proved).

Therefore they must be the same physical state, i.e. the same ket(upto a multiplicative factor, which is $C_\epsilon$). Note that eigenvectors of some observable, call them $x$ and $\lambda x$, will have the same eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $a|\epsilon\rangle$ is an eigenstate of eigenvalue $(\epsilon-1)$. But just because $|\epsilon\rangle$ is normalized doesn't mean $a|\epsilon\rangle$ is. If you write the NORMALIZED eigenstate of $H$ with eigenvalue $(\epsilon-1)$ as $|\epsilon-1\rangle$, then the best you can say is that $a|\epsilon\rangle$ is proportional to this state.